# Setting up a UINavigation controller and various view loads

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have setup a UINavigation controller that uses the AppDelegate as the main point of contact.

I have different methods which run such as presentHomeViewController, presentLoginViewController, which push the different view controllers to the Navigation Controller.

App Delegate - didFinishLaunching

```
welcomeViewController = [[MyWelcomeViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyWelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcomeViewController];
navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

self.revealSideViewController = [[PPRevealSideViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];

[self.revealSideViewController setDirectionsToShowBounce:PPRevealSideDirectionNone];
[self.revealSideViewController setPanInteractionsWhenClosed:PPRevealSideInteractionContentView | PPRevealSideInteractionNavigationBar];

self.window.rootViewController = self.revealSideViewController;
```

Is this the correct process for this?

```
- (void)presentHomeViewController {
// We start by dismissing the ModalViewConrtoller which is LoginViewController from the welcomeview
[self.welcomeViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// Check if the home view controller already exists if not create one
if (!self.homeViewController) {
    NSLog(@"presentHomeViewController- Creating the Home View controller");
    homeViewController = [[MyHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
}

// Push the homeViewController onto the navController
NSLog(@"presentHomeViewController");
self.navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navController setTitle:@"Home"];
[self.navController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:NO];
```

If I then add the following to a different class :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:accountViewController animated:NO];
```

No view is pushed to the stack, should I control all the movement within the AppDelegate as I have been doing, or is there betters way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Thanks for posting your code. So, to address your final question first, I don't recommend controlling your navigation stack from the app delegate. You should be controlling the stack from the view controllers that are the children of the navigation controller.

To that point, remember the hierarchy of view controllers: `UINavigationController` inherits from `UIViewController`, and `UIViewController` has properties defined for all the things you'd see in a navigation layout such navigation items and title. More importantly, it also has properties for its parent view controllers, the view controller that presented it, and its navigation controller. So, considering the hierarchy, your app delegate should only instantiate the navigation controller's root VC and the nav controller itself, and then subsequently set the nav controller's root VC.

From there, you should be pushing and popping other VCs from the VCs themselves. Remember, every VC has a property that's automatically set to point at the navigation controller it's a part of. That's why `[self.navigationController pushViewController:]` works. For instance, if I have a nav controller whose root VC is a `UITableViewController`, and tapping on one of the items in the table view pushed a new VC onto the stack, I would push that VC from the table VC and not from the nav controller class or the app delegate.

Sorry if that's confusing. Please let me know if that needs clarification and I'll give it my best. Otherwise, hopefully that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Sorry, I use a reveal side controller and didnt want to confuse the situation by showing that too, trying to keep it simple. I have updated the question with information though. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, so when I try to run a self.navigationController presentViewController I get an error 'No visable @interface or UINavigationController declares the selector presentViewController... Does this mean I have to init a navigation controller in every single view controller?

Comment: Are you sending presentViewController:animated:completion: from the app delegate? If so, the app delegate doesn't inherit from `UIViewController`, and thus will not implement that method. Unless you have something like a `UITabBarController`, you don't need to init a new `UINavigationController` for every view controller. You only need to init ONE nav controller, set a root VC for it, and then call presentViewController:... from the root VC and any other VC that might have been pushed from somewhere in that chain. The `navigationController` property will point to the main nav controller.

Comment: I am actually trying to presentViewController from a sub class of UITableViewController. In this circumstance should I init a new Navigation Controller then presentViewController OR use the AppDelgate in the circumstance when presenting from a non UIViewController class?

Comment: Have a look at this crude diagram I whipped up: http://i46.tinypic.com/14qyhv.png. All your AppDelegate should do as far as views are concerned is initialize an instance of your tableview subclass and a navigation controller, set the tableview instance as the nav controller's root VC, and set the nav controller as the window's root VC. From there, all navigation should be handled by the individual VCs because anything that came from the nav controller's root VC will point back to that nav controller. You don't need a nav controller for each view controller you want to present.

Comment: Quick edit and big oversight/mistake on my part: use `pushViewController:animated:` instead of `presentViewController:...` with self.navigationController. This would definitely explain the "no visible interface" error you got. Otherwise, everything else in the diagram and what I've said in my previous comments regarding the view hierarchy and what to do/not to do in the app delegate is still correct :)